# Replace <li> node into anchors with href in for loop

Tags: javascript, css, html, href

Theoretically, this code should write Paragraph 1-4 into links to www.bing.ca with Paragraph (Number) as the text.  I have been working on finding the error for a couple days now and I am failing miserably.  Any help would be appreciated.  This is my first question ever, so if I could have made it any better for future reference to others, I'd appreciate that as well.  Thank you.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title></title>
  <script>
  window.onload = function() {
     var innerDiv = document.getElementById("innerDiv");
     var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
     for (var i = 0; i < innerDiv.childNodes.length; i++) {
        var anchor = 
           newDiv.appendChild(document.createElement("a"));
        anchor.setAttribute("href", "http://www.bing.ca");
        anchor.text = innerDiv.childNodes[i].textContent;
        newDiv.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
}
innerDiv.replaceNode(newDiv);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="outerDiv">
      <p class='mainPara'>Main Paragraph</p>
   <ul>
      <li>First List Item</li>
      <li>Second List Item</li>
      <li>Third List Item</li>
      <li>Fourth List Item</li>
   </ul>
   <div id="innerDiv">
      <p class='subPara' id='P1'>Paragraph 1</p>
      <p class='subPara' id='P2'>Paragraph 2</p>
      <p class='subPara' id='P3'>Paragraph 3</p>
      <p class='subPara' id='P4'>Paragraph 4</p>
   </div>
   <table>
   </table>
   <input type="text"/><input type="submit" value="Submit!">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: One big way to make your next question better, skip the profanity.

Comment: Thanks.  I was just about to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `replaceNode` is **IE only** (http://help.dottoro.com/ljxvjvcg.php). Perhaps use `innerHTML` instead.

```js
var innerDiv = document.getElementById("innerDiv");
var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
for (var i = 0; i < innerDiv.childNodes.length; i++) {
  var anchor =
    newDiv.appendChild(document.createElement("a"));
  anchor.setAttribute("href", "http://www.bing.ca");
  anchor.text = innerDiv.childNodes[i].textContent;
  newDiv.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
}
innerDiv.innerHTML = newDiv.innerHTML;
```

```html
<div id="outerDiv">
  <p class='mainPara'>Main Paragraph</p>
  <ul>
    <li>First List Item</li>
    <li>Second List Item</li>
    <li>Third List Item</li>
    <li>Fourth List Item</li>
  </ul>
  <div id="innerDiv">
    <p class='subPara' id='P1'>Paragraph 1</p>
    <p class='subPara' id='P2'>Paragraph 2</p>
    <p class='subPara' id='P3'>Paragraph 3</p>
    <p class='subPara' id='P4'>Paragraph 4</p>
  </div>
  <table>
  </table>
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit!">
```

**Always** check your console for errors, or turn javascript errors on in your browser for debugging. A quick check of your console would have shown

> TypeError: innerDiv.replaceNode is not a function

and you would have been well on the way to solving your problem yourself.

Comment: YES! YES! YES!  That was it!  You are a miracle man!  I was pouring over this code forever.  I appreciate your input.  The problem was that I was writing my code in Chrome and using replaceNode.  Wow.  It looks like it will take some time figuring out which methods only pertain to certain browsers. Goodness.

Comment: No problem. Up vote and accept the answer when you can. Browser compatibility is not the problem it used to be. When you have the basic of javascript down look at the [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) library it will ease many cross browser headaches, just make sure you understand the fundamentals of javascript first. Finally get to know some of the handy tools: Chrome Developer Tools (press f12), IE Developer Tools (f12) &  FireBug for firefox (a plug in)

Comment: Wow.  Thank you jsve.  F12 is now my new found friend.

Comment: I would upvote but apparently I don't have a good enough reputation, yet.  I would if I could!